# How to use a method in render reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i have a method set_data which is used to set data based on id. I know it could be easy to call this set_data in componentdidupdate when id changes. However in doing so it doesnt set some state variables in the parent component.

To get rid of that want to call set_data method in render . However since this set_data method sets state of data it enters into an infinite loop in render . Also cannot provide a condition (like prevprops.id!== this.props.id) to execute set_data method.

To prevent it thought of using this set_data method not to set state at all. and can call this set_data method in render. 
Below is the code,

```
export default class child extends React.Component {
state = {
    query: '',
    data: null,
};
empty_id = 0xffffffff;

componentDidMount() {
    this.set_open_data();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
        this.set_data();
   }
}

set_data = () => {
    if (!this.props.info) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.props.id === this.empty_id) {
        this.setState({data: null});
        return;
    }

    let data = {
        info: [],
        values: [],
    };
    const info = this.props.info;
    for (let i=0, ii=info.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (info[i].meshes.includes(this.props.id)) {
            const info = info[i].info;
            const values = info[i].values;
            data = {
                info: typeof info === 'string' ? info.split('\r\n') : [],
                values: values ? values : [],
            };
            break;
        }
    }
    this.setState({data: this.filter_data(data, this.state.query)});
  };
  render = () => {
      const shown_data= this.state.data;  
      /* i want to call set_data method here*/};}
```

Could someone help me solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't call setData there, because that would be anti-pattern. It will trigger a loop that will continuously render as well as keeps setting state.
2. You can probably rewrite the component this way:

```
export default class child extends React.Component {
  state = {
     query: ''
  };
  empty_id = 0xffffffff;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.set_open_data();
  }

  set_data = () => {
    let data = {};
    if (!this.props.info) {
      return data;
    }
    if (this.props.id === this.empty_id) {
      return data;
    }

    let data = {
      info: [],
      values: [],
    };
    const info = this.props.info;
    for (let i=0, ii=info.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (info[i].meshes.includes(this.props.id)) {
            const info = info[i].info;
            const values = info[i].values;
            data = {
                info: typeof info === 'string' ? info.split('\r\n') : [],
                values: values ? values : [],
            };
            break;
        }
    }
    data = this.filter_data(data, this.state.query);
    return data;
  };

  render = () => {
      const shown_data= this.state.data; 
      const data = this.set_data(); 
      /* i want to call set_data method here*/};}
```

In this, we are not setting data in the state. For every new ID, it will get new data and will compute it from render thereby avoiding antipattern. I have also removed componentDidMount, since we are doing computation in render. Note: This solution means taking away data from the state, if you are not using `data` anywhere before render, this will work.

Let me know if this helps.